# Is `innodb_table_locks=0` a good idea?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have noticed several times that triggers in mysql cause table locks on each and every table referenced in the trigger. Even if not actually touched, like when it's inside an `IF` statement.
If I understand the MySql (8.x) docs correctly, setting `innodb_table_locks=0` will disable those.

Now will that have any negative effect on a mysql server?
Any performance/stability/integrity effects?

Any reason I'd even want full table locks by triggers (as opposed to single queries)? (Except for maybe easier deadlock detection?)

Thanks!

Comment: The ref manual is rather vague on this topic. ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-transaction-model.html )  I would not use =0 without further research.  Are your Triggers causing to much sluggishness?  Consider moving the Stored Procs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use LOCK TABLES WRITE to lock a table, then you make a change to that table, and it invokes a trigger, and in that trigger, other tables are accessed. The default behavior is that the other tables become locked.

If you set `innodb_table_locks=0`, then the other tables accessed by those triggers are not locked.

So if other sessions have a few row locks in the other tables, this would help, because your action that invoked the trigger would not have to wait for a table lock.

On the other hand, if your trigger code was depending on exclusive access to the other tables to avoid race conditions, you could spoil that, and get race conditions that are hard to debug.

This is all moot if you don't use LOCK TABLES WRITE in your normal usage of tables.

Comment: I never use LOCK TABLES, trying to use as little locks as possible. Design everything so there's no implicit corruption of data by concurrently inserted rows etc.
The reason I'm investigating this, is that I notice that calling a trigger - initiates locks on all involved tables - even if the whole trigger code is inside an "IF FALSE THEN ....". And that does not really makes sense. Locks should be acquire on demand.

Comment: I don't have a test case to demonstrate it, but my reading of the documentation is that in your case, since you do not use LOCK TABLES, the locking will not act differently if you set `innodb_table_locks=0`.

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked, because the docs are not very clear about it. Is there any other way to disable the automatic locking from triggers?

Comment: Wait, do transactions count the same as "lock tables" too?

Comment: No, transactions don't count as lock tables. Why do you think there is table locking happening? If you're not using LOCK TABLES yourself, it shouldn't be. But there may be row locking happening, which is blocking your concurrent updates.